# Writing an unit test for a service

Tags: php, unit-testing, service, phpunit, repository

Trying PHP unit testing. I have read the [PHPUnit documentation](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/7.4/index.html) and watched [Sandi Metz' video about unit testing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=URSWYvyc42M), but I have difficulties to apply all this in a real world scenario.

I decided to unit test my `CallReceiver` class which takes some parameters and passes the entity to a repository for saving:

```
final class CallReceiver {

   private $CallRepository;

   public function __construct( CallRepository $CallRepository ) {

    $this->CallRepository = $CallRepository;
   }

   public function receive( string $uuid, string $Destination, string $Caller ) : void {

    $Call = Call::receive(
        CallId::createValidated( $uuid ),
        DestinationNumber::createValidated( $Destination ),
        $Caller
    );

    $this->CallRepository->save( $Call );
   }

}
```

According to Sandi, I would have to test that the `Call` entity gets sent to `CallRepository` (outgoing command). So I suppose I will have to mock both `Call` and `CallRepository`:

```
public function testReceive() {

    $CallRepository = $this->getMockBuilder(CallRepository::class)
        ->setMethods(['save'])
        ->getMock();

    $Call = $this->createMock(Call::class);

    $CallRepository->expects($this->once())
        ->method('save')
        ->with($this->equalTo($Call));

    $CallReceiver = new CallReceiver( $CallRepository );

    $CallReceiver->receive( '123', '456', '789' );

}
```

But that doesn't really work. How would I write a meaningful test for the `CallReveiver::receive` method?

Comment: You are close, but you can't mock the `$Call` variable since it gets created in the function that you are testing. The reason that it fails right now is because it expects the function `save` to be called with a different `$Call` than it actually is called with. And that is fine. You can create a new test for your `Call` class that tests if those objects are created successfully, but that's not part of this test. This test just wants to make sure that the repository is being called correctly. So if you remove the `->with()` part of the assertion it should work just fine.

Comment: In theory, if you do want to check if it's being called with the correct `$Call` object, you can replace the `$Call = $this->createMock(Call::class);` line with an actual call to the `Call` class to create an identical object.

Comment: The problem is that `Call` has dependencies, or to be more specific, it expects certain types as parameters upon creation. Something like `new Call( uuid $uuid );` I guess I can't mock these either and would have to use the actual `uuid` value object?

Comment: I created stubs for the type hinted parameters of  `Call` and the test runs fine now.